# Convert php to bash script?

Tags: php, bash

I have an API function written in php and want to convert to bash script, in shell to run in some simple environment. Is there any tool for that or have to code manually?
Could anyone assist? Thank you and your help will be highly appreciated.

```
<?php

$accessKey = 'xxxx';
$secretKey = 'xxxx';
$baseUri = 'http://xxx:9989/';

$yl = new YLOpenApi($accessKey, $secretKey, $baseUri);


$regionAllUri = "api/open/v1/manager/region/getAll";
var_dump($yl->get($regionAllUri));

$deviceEditUri = "api/open/v1/manager/device/getEdit";
//var_dump($yl->get($deviceEditUri,["id"=>"1213"]));

$deviceListUri = "api/open/v1/manager/device/getList";
$postDeviceListData = [
    "limit" => 20
];
//var_dump($yl->post($deviceListUri, json_encode($postDeviceListData)));


$file = new CURLFile("F:\\000000000079-all.cfg");
$addGroupConfigUri = "api/open/v1/manager/groupConfig/add";
$addGroupData = [
    'file'=>$file,
    'name'=>'open api test'
];

//var_dump($yl->form($addGroupConfigUri,$addGroupData));


class YLOpenApi
{

    const LF = "\n";
    const GET = "GET";
    const POST = "POST";
    const CONTENT_TYPE_JSON = "Content-Type: application/json";

    private $accessKey;
    private $secretKey;
    private $baseUri;

    public function __construct($accessKey, $secretKey, $baseUri)
    {
        $this->secretKey = $secretKey;
        $this->accessKey = $accessKey;
        $this->baseUri = $baseUri;
    }

    public function get($uri, $query = [])
    {
        return $this->doRequest(self::GET, $uri, $query);
    }

    public function post($uri, $body = false)
    {
        return $this->doRequest(self::POST, $uri, [], $body, [self::CONTENT_TYPE_JSON]);
    }

    public function form($uri, $body = false)
    {
        return $this->doRequest(self::POST, $uri, [], $body);
    }

    private function doRequest($method, $uri, $query = [], $body = false, $headers = false)
    {

        list($signHeader, $queryParams) = $this->sign($method, $uri, $query, $body,!$headers);

        $ch = curl_init();
        $url = $this->getUrl($uri, $queryParams);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        if ($method != self::GET) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
        }

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $convertHeader = $this->convertCurlHeader($signHeader);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $convertHeader);

        if ($method != self::GET && $body) {

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
            if ($headers) {
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array_merge($convertHeader, $headers));
            }
        }

        var_dump($signHeader);

        if ($j = curl_exec($ch)) {
            return json_decode($j);
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }

    private function sign($method, $uri, $query = [], $body = false,$form = false)
    {
        $systemHeader['X-Ca-Key'] = $this->accessKey;
        $systemHeader['X-Ca-Nonce'] = sha1(uniqid('yl'));
        $systemHeader['X-Ca-Timestamp'] = intval(microtime(true) * 1000);
        if ($body && !$form) {
            $systemHeader['Content-MD5'] = base64_encode(md5($body, true));
        }
        ksort($systemHeader);
        $qs = null;
        if ($query) {
            ksort($query);
            $qs = http_build_query($query);
        }

        // build string to sign
        $toSign = $method;
        foreach ($systemHeader as $k => $v) {
            $toSign .= self::LF . $k . ':' . $v;
        }
        $toSign .= self::LF . $uri;
        if (isset($qs)) {
            $toSign .= self::LF . $qs;
        }

        $systemHeader['X-Ca-Signature'] = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', trim($toSign), $this->secretKey, true));
        return [$systemHeader, $qs];
    }

    private function getUrl($uri, $params)
    {

        return isset($params) ? $this->baseUri . $uri . '?' . $params : $this->baseUri . $uri;
    }

    public function convertCurlHeader($arr)
    {
        $header = [];
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
            $header[$i++] = $key . ": " . $val;
        }
        return $header;
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiast programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative solution**: You can execute a php script directly from a shell.

1: Add a shebang:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
....
```

2: make the php script executable

```
chmod a+x ./path/to/my.php
```

3: run the script

```
./path/to/my.php
# or
./path/to/my.php options_and_params
```